# Extracting data from specific subarray

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following array and I am trying to get data out of '[0]'.

```
Array (
  [ID] => 103088
  [key] => field_65002d05c4f14
  ... more elements
  [value] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
      [file_title] => Spec Sheet - with contents
      [file] => URL
    )
  )
  ... more elements
)
```

I have gone through to complete my `foreach` loop however I am getting no output - WordPress functions.php

```
foreach($arrayOBJ as $value => $file){
    //echo '<li><a href="'.$file['file'].'"></a>Some Text</li>';
}
```

I am expecting to be able to generate lines with "file" as the href and some text as the text.

Comment: `foreach($arrayOBJ['value'] as $file)`

Comment: `foreach ($arrayOBJ['value'] as ['file' => $file]) { echo '<li><a href="' . $file . '"></a>Some Text</li>'; }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:

```php
foreach($arrayOBJ['value'] as $file){
  //echo '<li><a href="'.$file['file'].'"></a>Some Text</li>';
}
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicate questions instead of posting code-only answers.